# Grab url iframe string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

String

```
let iframe = "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/111111\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
```

What I need is the src url string.

I've tried an expression that gets most of it.

```
let url = iframe.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+);
```

This returns

```
'https://player.vimeo.com/video/111111\"'
```

It's returning the final \ and " which I don't want. I've tried to use something like

```
[^\"]
```

to say "don't include the \ or " but I'm not getting it right.

Regex is always a bear for me.

Comment: Replace `\S` with `[^\\]`. This might not cover all cases though, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3809401/4934172).

Comment: @ Ahmed Ah, thank you. I was close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Answer (score 1):

Can use DOM methods by inserting the html into an empty container element and getting the `src` property of the iframe element

```js
let iframe = "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/111111\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

let div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = iframe

let url = div.querySelector('iframe').src

console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```js
let iframe = "<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/111111\" width=\"500\" height=\"281\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

console.log(iframe.match('(?<=src=").*?(?=[\?"])'));
```